# Filtering Pandas DataFrame by value in a column's lists

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame that has a column of lists. I would like to return a subset of the Dataframe of those rows whose list contains a specified value.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'detail_id': [10000, 10001, 10002], 
                     'tokens': [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'D'], ['C', 'E', 'F', 'H']]})
```

If I filter by for a particular ID this way it works

```
test[test['detail_id'] == 10001]
```

If I just want the first 2 rows that have 'A' in their tokens lists, the following does not work

```
test['A' in test['tokens']]
```

I get a `KeyError: False`. I understand why, but I'm struggling to figure out a solution. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `numpy.bitwise_and`:

```py
import numpy as np

test.loc[np.bitwise_and(test['tokens'].map(set), {'A'})]
```

Read some more: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_and.html

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. This was very informative.

Answer (score 0):

A good night's sleep and a re-reading of the [selection documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) has helped me figure it out. The documentation says that selection can accept a "boolean array". So that's what I've done.

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({'detail_id': [10000, 10001, 10002, 10003], 
                     'tokens': [['A', 'B', 'C'], 
                                ['A', 'D'], 
                                ['C', 'E', 'F', 'H'], 
                                ['X', 'YA', 'Z']]})

def has_a(row):
    return 'A' in row['tokens']

test[test.apply(has_a, axis=1)]
```

This code only returns the first 2 rows as desired.

Comment: Avoid `.apply(...)` - in short - it performs like a simple loop, some details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432584/11610186 you should rather try leveraging vectorized processing - that's what `numpy`-s (and by inheritance `pandas` too) is about - see my answer as an example.